# How do I write a Linux sosreport plugin?

Tags: python, linux

How do I write a Linux sosreport plugin? I have been looking at python code that creates a plugin for the linux sosreport command. But I have not been able to find a link on the internet that describes how to write and implement a plugin for the sosreport. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The second result when I googled "implement a plugin for the sosreport" is this [tutorial](https://github.com/sosreport/sosreport/wiki/How-to-Write-a-Plugin).

If this isn't what you are looking for, then you should be more specific: mention what you have tried and what specific problem you are having. Questions should show at least a basic amount of research / effort.